# Spring data mongodb auditing not working.. (Java config)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

i'm currently using Spring data mongodb 1.6.0-RELEASE and i know it has auditing feature. I
put `@EnableMongoAuditing` annotation on top of my configuration class. And my bean is below:

```
@Document
public class MyBean{

@Id
private AnotherCustomBean anotherCustomBean = new AnotherCustomBean();

@CreatedDate
private Date creationDate;

@LastModifiedDate
private Date lastModifiedDate;

.
.
.
```

When i save this bean with `mongoTemplate.save(myBean);` it's not setting created date and last modified date...And it has no errors.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should add this property into your bean so we need to tell **Spring** who is a current saving property.@CreatedBy  
 private String createdBy; Another idea, the annotations can be applied selectively, depending on which information you’d like to capture. For the annotations capturing the points in time can be used on properties of type JodaTimes DateTime, legacy Java Date and Calendar, JDK8 date/time types as well as long/Long

Comment: Actually @CreatedBy annotation is not compulsory, also joda-time is on classpath already so should be no problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual problem was the `@Id` annotation. To use spring auditing properly, you have to define an ObjectId (null for new saved objects), thats how spring decide `@LastModifiedDate` and `@CreatedDate`

Afterwards, i found a way to make it possible use custom beans on `@Id` by implementing `Auditable<String,String>`

Thanks to @Felby:

> I found that the @Id field needed to be null at the time of save()
>   only for the @CreatedDate and @CreatedBy annotations. The
>   @LastModifiedDate and @LastModifiedBy fields worked regardless of
>   whether the @Id field was initialized or not.

Comment: I found that the `@Id` field needed to be `null` at the time of `save()` only for the `@CreatedDate` and `@CreatedBy` annotations.  The `@LastModifiedDate` and `@LastModifiedBy` fields worked regardless of whether the `@Id` field was initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but try to add joda-time to classpath to use date-related audit annotations

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```