# Mongotemplate.updateFirst() doesn't update @LastModifiedDate

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using annotation based configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class ApplicationDataConfig ....
```

And I also have `@LastModifiedDate`, `@CreatedDate` annotation set on fields of type `org.joda.time.DateTime`. When I use

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository.save(entity)

both the audit fields are updated just fine. But when I use

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateFirst()/updateMulti()

the lastupdated time is not being updated. Does anybody have a clue of what could be wrong? I'm using spring-data-mongodb1.8.3

Comment: Any progress? @Sofiia is asking (as an answer :/)

Comment: @srini-kandula did you find a solution? i have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported now. There is a ticket so you can track progress: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1797

Answer (score -2):

> I found that the @Id field needed to be null at the time of save()
>   only for the @CreatedDate and @CreatedBy annotations. The
>   @LastModifiedDate and @LastModifiedBy fields worked regardless of
>   whether the @Id field was initialized or not.

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31018339/5939750