# Spring Data MongoDB - Annotation @CreatedDate does not work while using with custom Id field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a simple Persistable Class:

```
public class Profile implements Persistable<String>{

    @Id
    private String username;

    @CreatedDate
    public Date createdDate;

    public Profile(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return username == null;
    }
}
```

And a simple repository:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, String> {

}
```

**My Spring Boot Application class is also annotated with @EnableMongoAuditing.** But i still can't get the annotation @CreatedDate work.

ProfileRepository.save(new Profile("user1")) writes the entity without the field createdDate. What do i do wrong?

**EDIT:** This is my Application class (without @EnableMongoRepositories, but it works since the repositories are in the sub-packages i guess)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Also adding the annotation EnableMongoRepositories did not change anything.

Comment: it worked for me...

Comment: strange.. for 2 hours i am trying to find out why it does not work for me. I have created my entity with its Id "new Profile("username")", and then saved it. Could you also try it that way

Comment: Can you show the configuration ? You have @EnableMongoRepositories
 I Guess.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i have edited the entry.

Comment: maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584271/spring-data-mongodb-annotation-createddate-isnt-working-when-id-is-assigned-m

Comment: @Jerry06 no i have already seen it. (In my example i create every time a new entity)

Comment: i see this is just not working when using the custom id like `new Profile("username")`. You should update the question I guess.

Comment: @Jerry06 ok thank you.

Comment: In your case as you always have username set spring repository always try to process entity as update(save) rather than insert because isNew always return false. So the createdDate field is never set. I bet if you include lastModified field it will be set.Try implementing `Auditable` interface and set the audit fields yourself in case of custom id. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729310/spring-data-mongodb-auditing-not-working-java-config)

Comment: On further thinking may be rolling our own implementation of `Auditable` may not work because isNew will return false and spring repository will copy only the lastModifed field from entity. So it looks like you have to update the isNew implementation to differentiate between insert and update request.

Comment: @Veeram indeed, LastModifiedDate works.. I will try that with Auditable. thank you!

Comment: @Veeram I think i will then stay with my own manual createdDate fields for now. It is just another attribute in class. The solution with Auditable seems more cumbersome.. Thank you though!

Comment: your id strategy and isNew() implementation is wrong

Answer (score 7):

simply just add `@Version` field to you `@Document` class and leave `@EnableMongoAuditing` i.e.

```
@Document
public class Profile implements Persistable<String>{

     @Version      
     private Long version;
    
     @Id
     private String username;

     @CreatedDate
     public Date createdDate;

     public Profile(String username) {
         this.username = username;
     }

     @Override
     public String getId() {
         return username;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isNew() {
         return username == null;
     }
 }
```

Here is a related issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-946

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem myself, it happens because you are creating the id yourself.

```
public Profile(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

By doing this, mongo thinks it is not a new object and doesn't use the @CreatedDate annotation. You could also use the @Document annotation instead of implementing the Persistable Class, like this:

```
@Document
public class Profile{}
```

Comment: By the way, you should never set username as an id, what if you decide that a username can change. An id should never change, I suggest you make 2 variables, Id and Username.

Comment: You don't know the domain I can imagine examples from real life where username can become a valid ID

Comment: In my eyes it's still a bad practice.

Comment: Well, IMHO in general we should prefer natural primary keys. Of course we can't break invariants such that e.g. a name can change. Just choose natural primary keys over surrogates when it's possible

Comment: but anyway, i think the problem above is occurring because he is using a natural id, an id he is defining himself. if he would use a generated id (generated by mongo) the creationDate would work.

Comment: If he would use generated ID this problem would be solved, but he'd lose natural key. IMHO it's always better to choose domain over technologoy - making solutions that fit the domain, not the framework that you currently use. His problem is purely technical and changing domain to solve technical problem is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

As described in Spring Data MongoDB issue [DATAMONGO-946](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1872), the created date functionality uses the [`isNew()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html#isNew--) method to determine whether the created date should be set since the entity is new.  In your case, your `isNew` method is always returning false, since the `username` is always set.

The comments in the issue presents two possible solutions to this problem.

### `Persistable` solution

The first option is to fix the `isNew` strategy so that it correctly registers new objects.  One way suggested in the comments would be to change the implementation to check the `createdDate` field itself, since it should only be set on non-new objects.

```java
@Override
public boolean isNew() {
    return createdDate == null;
}
```

### Persistent entity solution

The second option is to change from implementing `Persistable` to instead use a persistent entity and use the [`@Version`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Version.html) annotation to inject a `version` property in the persisted MongoDB entity.  Note that this *will* change how the data is persisted, as it adds an auto-incrementing `version` field to the data.

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Profile {
    @Id
    private String username;

    @CreatedDate
    public Date createdDate;

    @Version
    public Integer version;

    public Profile(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it does not work for reactive MongoDB (WebFlux Spring Boot + reactive MongoDB). I tried and it does not add `createdDate`. Does anybody know if it is applicable for reactive MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

If that's your real class (`Profile`) then there's nothing you can do with standard tools.

Your `isNew` method will always return `false`, because you set the username by yourself and when `Profile` is about to be saved by Spring it will check the `isNew` and you probably have `username` already set. `@LastModifiedDate` would work in your case, but `@CreatedDate` won't.

If you haven't got other fields that you can use in `isNew` method then you have to set the value of `createdDate` manually (or maybe there's some kind of interceptor that may wrap all mongo template method, but I wouldn't go that way).

For example, check if profile with given username already exists in DB, if so just get it's createdDate(you can use projection here) and set to the profile that you're about to save. Otherwise set createdDate to new date.

Answer (score -1):

For me, i just do it as:

```
    @CreatedDate
    @Field("created_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();
```

And make sure the Get/Set is available.
Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar situation where I needed to set the id manually sometimes and there really is no way to know ahead of time if the id will be a new one or an update without first searching the database to be sure.  I also know that over the lifetime of the entity, I will be updating my entity many times, but creating it only once.  So to avoid the extra database operations, I went with this solution:

```
    Profile savedProfile = profileRepo.save(profile);
    if (savedProfile.getCreatedDate() == null ){
        savedProfile.setCreatedDate(savedProfile.getLastModifiedDate());
        savedProfile = profileRepo.save(profile);
    }
```

This is taking advantage of the fact that I also have a `@LastModifiedDate` field on Profile as well that is always updated by spring data when an entity is saved.