# @CreatedDate not working when i set _id manually in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

i faced an issue when i used ObjectId as datatype for _id and i used @createdDate annotitation with createdOn it is work fine and every pirsist into mongodb get date but when i set id manullay as you in my case below it is not woking :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I74i9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp15G.png)

and i am also enableMongoAuduiting 
how i let @createdDate work with custom generated id ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data MongoDB - Annotation @CreatedDate does not work while using with custom Id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054719/spring-data-mongodb-annotation-createddate-does-not-work-while-using-with-cus)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code inside your post instead of as images? It's easier to read this way, and helps with editting your post if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting id manually in that you can use the following workaround in entity class

```
@PostConstruct
protected void onCreate() {
  if(this.createdOn == null) {
     this.createdOn = new Date();
  }
}
```